# Can MySQL use memory for temporary GROUP BY table?

Tags: mysql, memory, group-by, temp-tables

I need to optimize some `GROUP BY` queries

One option is to use indexes as explained in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-optimization.html)

Since my `GROUP BY` will be applied on complex queries with nested subqueries, I can't use indexes unless I design myself the temporary table to store the intermediate result and then apply the `GROUP BY`, this could even be a memory table
Is it worth calculating an index that will be used only once ?

In a first lazy approach, as I'm not very motivated to rewrite all the queries, is it possible to tell MySQL to use memory for the internal temporary tables ?

Are there other options ?

Comment: Note that MySQL can (sometimes) keep an index on the result of a subquery.

Comment: You might also want to read this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Created_tmp_disk_tables

Comment: Are internal temp tables always in-memory until too large ?

Comment: Looks like that. At least that's what I understand from documentation. See also [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/internal-temporary-tables.html) - under Internal Temporary Table Storage Engine"

Comment: Yes I read "If the server creates the table on disk (**either initially** or by converting an in-memory table)", that makes me wonder when the server decides to do it initially

Comment: [big_tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_big_tables) - "If set to 1, all temporary tables are stored on disk rather than in memory."